# Busca em array que contém string e number

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js, vuex

Olá, possuo um array com a seguinte extrutura

```
ddd: [
    'SP', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
    'RJ', 21, 22, 24, 'ES', 27, 28,
    'MG', 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38,
    'PR', 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 'SC', 47, 48, 49,
    'RS', 51, 53, 54, 55,
    'TO', 63, 'GO', 61, 62, 64, 'MT', 65, 66, 'MS', 67, 'AC', 68, 'RO', 69,
    'BA', 71, 73, 74, 75, 77, 'SE', 79,
    'PE', 81, 87, 'AL', 82, 'PB', 83, 'RN', 84, 'CE', 85, 88, 'PI', 89, 86,
    'PA', 91, 93, 94, 'AP', 92, 96, 'RR', 95, 'AM', 97, 'MA', 98, 99,
    'DF'
  ]
```

E eu verifico se o `ddd` que digitei é valido desta forma:

```
ddd.map(String).includes(value.substring(0, 2)))
```

Isso funciona, a pergunta é, existe como filtrar na hora de verificar?

Exemplo:

```
1) saber ddd = ddd.map(String).includes(value.substring(0, 2)))
2) saber estado = ddd.includes(value))
```

No caso, o exemplo 1 e 2 irão funcionar perfeitamente caso eu solicite value = 11 ou value igual a SP pois os 2 constam na extrutura, o que eu gostaria de saber é o seguinte, teria como ao localisar SP eu retornar só os DDDs que seguem de SP ou seja 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ou de qualquer outro estado.

Exemplo:

```
value = 'RJ'
retorno = ddd.includes(value)) // imprime true pois RJ existe
retornoDDD = naoseiseepossivel // como eu retornaria 21, 22, 24 nesta variável?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como o seu `array` é composto de string e os números em seguida, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

1 - Procurar o índice do estado com a função [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

2 - Obter os números seguintes a partir da posição do estado até houver outra `string`, indicando que acabou os DDD's daquele estado buscado.

Você pode fazer isso verificando o tipo do dado do array através o operador [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), que retorna o tipo em uma string.

A função ficaria assim:

```
var value = 'RJ'
var retorno = ddd.includes(value));
var retornoDDD = retornarDDD(value);

function retornarDDD(estado) {
    var numerosDDD = [];
    var pos = ddd.indexOf(estado) + 1;

    for (var i = pos; i < ddd.length; i++) {
        if (typeof ddd[i] == 'number') {
            numerosDDD.push(ddd[i]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return numerosDDD; // Retorna [21, 22, 24]
}
```

Caso houver uma sigla de estado inválido no seu array, ele retornará vazio.

Comment: perfeito, eu imaginava algo assim, pegar o que vem entre 2 strings, por isso montei com esta estrutura, existam 2 estruturas, uma para ddd e outra para estado e então uni as duas as organizando desta forma, só não sabia como eu faria ou se era possível, mas mesmo caso não fosse, eu tinha 1 array em vez de 2 mas fiquei feliz que é possível e funciona muito bem, sua função é bem simples e fácil de entender, muito legal, obrigado